# Python win32gui app window flickers

Tags: python, win32gui

I have been having a problem with win32gui while taking screenshot of certain application window.

My script (code below) take a screenshot of a window to analyze it. For certain windows it works perfectly, but I have just encountered one application that, while I have my script running the window that it takes screenshot from make the window flickers. (I keep seeing white flash on the whole window)

Anyone ever experienced it and had a solution for it?

```
def getImage(self,hwnd = None):
    if hwnd == None:
        hwnd = self.hwnd
    self.whereIsWindow(hwnd)

    left, top, right, bot = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)

    w = right - left
    h = bot - top
    self.width = w
    self.height = h
    hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    mfcDC = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDC)
    saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()
    saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, w, h)
    saveDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)

    result = windll.user32.PrintWindow(hwnd, saveDC.GetSafeHdc(), 0)
    bmpinfo = saveBitMap.GetInfo()
    bmpstr = saveBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)

    im = Image.frombuffer(
        'RGB',
        (bmpinfo['bmWidth'], bmpinfo['bmHeight']),
        bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)

    win32gui.DeleteObject(saveBitMap.GetHandle())
    saveDC.DeleteDC()
    mfcDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwndDC)
```

I know the culprit are the last 5 lines, if i comment them out it stops flickering but it takes all the memory which is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting more of a delay in my loop and there was no flickering at all.